# Как вывести значение запроса?

Tags: java

```
@Test
public void test2 () {
        given()
            .param("q","9789652868374")
            .get("https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes")
            .then()
            .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
            .extract()
            .path("$.items[0].kind");
}
```

вывод

```
[TestNG] Running:
  /home/hp/.IdeaIC2017.1/system/temp-testng-customsuite.xml
===============================================
Default Suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Process finished with exit code 0[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Даю подсказку, значение надо не только извлечь, но и сохранить в переменной. А вывести переменную может любой, кто видел _Hello World_.

Answer (score 0):

```
String itemKind = given()
                   .param("q", "9789652868374")
                   .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
                   .get("https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes")
                   .then()
                   .extract()
                   .path("items[0].kind");
System.out.println("Kind: " + itemKind);
```